# "хотеть" versus impersonal "хотеться"

Tags: выбор-слова, глаголы

What is the difference in meaning between the following pairs?

1a) Я **хочу** овчарку.

1b) Мне **хочется** овчарку.

2a) Он так **хотел** новую машину!

2b) Ему так **хотелось** новую машину!

3a) Я **захотел** поесть.

3b) Мне **захотелось** поесть.

4a) Ребёнок **захотел** конфету.

4b) Ребёнку **захотелось** конфету.

Comment: There is no difference in meaning. The sentences in every pair are totally interchangeable.

Comment: `What is the difference` Quite close to "I want" vs "I would like".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's acceptable but stylistically flawed to use the impersonal construct with an identified direct object (one which you would have used with "the" in English).

You examples 1b and 4b sound a little bit peculiar out of context.

1b would have made sense in this conversation:

> — Я обещал тебе на день рождения собаку. Хочешь, я куплю тебе таксу?
>
> — Спасибо, но мне хочется овчарку.

, which makes clear it's not about any particular dog but rather the breed in general.

4b is better worded this way:

> Ребёнку захотелось конфет

or

> Ребёнку захотелось конфеты

, again, for the same reason.